# Foreach, last condition don't need "OK" for every vm it finds

Tags: powershell, if-statement, powercli, vmware-tools

I have a script that is supposed to have 3 different exit codes:
OK 0
Warning 1
Critical 2

I want it to only write output for each of these depending on conditions and it works fine for 1 and 2 since I want to display the name of the vm's. The reason I use array is because I might want to display the VM's with "Warning" for other purposes.

The problem I have is that this script will write "OK" for each vm that doesn't meet the other criteria. I simply need one "OK", that nothing needs to be done if no other criteria is met. I need help with the overall logic of this script.

```
$old = @()
$noinstall = @()
$status = 0
$vmtools = Get-VM | select name, @{N = ”ToolsStatus”; E = { $_.Extensiondata.Summary.Guest.ToolsStatus } }

foreach ($vmtool in $vmtools) {
    if (($vmtool.ToolsStatus) -eq 'toolsOld') {
        $arraytest1 = Write-Output "CRITICAL: $($vmtool.Name) ------ $($vmtool.ToolsStatus)"
        $old += , $arraytest1
        $Status = 2
        Write-output $old

    }
    elseif (($vmtool.Toolsstatus) -eq 'toolsNotInstalled' -And $status -ne 2) {
        Write-output "WARNING: $($vmtool.Name) ------ $($vmtool.ToolsStatus)"
        $status = 1
    }
    elseif (($vmtool.Toolsstatus) -eq 'toolsNotInstalled' -And $status -eq 2) {
        $arraytest = Write-output "WARNING: $($vmtool.Name) ------ $($vmtool.ToolsStatus)"
        $noinstall += , $arraytest
    }
    else {
        Write-Output "OK"
    }    
}
exit $status
```

Edit: I might as well just end with an elseif ($status -eq 0) right?
It will still write "OK" for every single vm though.

Comment: if you output `$vmtools.ToolsStatus`, do you see values like `toolsOld` and `toolsNotInstalled`? I tested this on PowerCLI 6.5, and it works like you expect.

Comment: @AdminOfThings Yeah I get the results as expected, and now I will only get "OK" if $status -eq 0.

But I don't want or need it to display "OK" for every vm it finds, since those vm's don't need a listing of any sort. Just need a "OK, everything's fine".

Comment: So you only want to display `OK` if the other criteria are ***never met*** for all of the VMs?

Comment: Just remove your `else { }` block. Outside of the `foreach` loop, test to see if `$status` is `0` --> `if ($status -eq 0) { Write-Output "OK" }`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to perform your overall status check outside of the `foreach` loop if you don't want to output for each iteration.

```
$status = 0
$vmtools = Get-VM | select name, @{N = ”ToolsStatus”; E = { $_.Extensiondata.Summary.Guest.ToolsStatus } }

foreach ($vmtool in $vmtools) {
    if (($vmtool.ToolsStatus) -eq 'toolsOld') {
        Write-Output "CRITICAL: $($vmtool.Name) ------ $($vmtool.ToolsStatus)"
        $Status = 2
    }
    elseif (($vmtool.Toolsstatus) -eq 'toolsNotInstalled' -And $status -ne 2) {
        Write-output "WARNING: $($vmtool.Name) ------ $($vmtool.ToolsStatus)"
        $status = 1
    }
    elseif (($vmtool.Toolsstatus) -eq 'toolsNotInstalled' -And $status -eq 2) {
        Write-output "WARNING: $($vmtool.Name) ------ $($vmtool.ToolsStatus)"
    } 
}
if ($status -eq 0) {
    Write-Output "OK"
}
```

---

Alternatively, you could collect the output of the `foreach` and then do a comparison afterwards.

```
$vmtools = Get-VM | select name, @{N = ”ToolsStatus”; E = { $_.Extensiondata.Summary.Guest.ToolsStatus } }

$output = foreach ($vmtool in $vmtools) {
    if (($vmtool.ToolsStatus) -eq 'toolsOld') {
        Write-Output "CRITICAL: $($vmtool.Name) ------ $($vmtool.ToolsStatus)"
    }
    elseif (($vmtool.Toolsstatus) -eq 'toolsNotInstalled') {
        Write-output "WARNING: $($vmtool.Name) ------ $($vmtool.ToolsStatus)"
    }
}
if (!$output) {
    Write-Output "OK"
}
```